# Android spinner not showing after changing the AppTheme

Tags: android, themes, spinner

I have a spinner in xml and declared as follows,

```
<com.xxx.CustomSpinnerNoDefaultSelection
    android:id="@+id/spinnerCommon"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

and on click of a button, am calling spinner.performClick(). It was working fine. But after changing the theme to the following one, it is not showing the spinner.

```
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Default">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">@dimen/activities_onehundredthirtyfivepixels</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

anyy idea, where am missing